# Reuse an Image with Canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, canvas

I have the following code;

```
export default async function draw(elRef : RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>, tileData : TileProps) {
  const canvas = elRef.current!;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')!;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  tileData.forEach(async tile => {
    const image = await loadImage(tile.tileType);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, tile.coordinates.x, tile.coordinates.y, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    })
}
```

Every time draw is called with an array of image src's to render onto the canvas, loadImage is called;

```
const loadImage = (tileType : string) : Promise<HTMLImageElement> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(image));
    image.addEventListener('error', reject);
    image.src = "./media/images/tiles/Dog.png";
  })
}
```

However, since draw will be constantly called, it's going to call loadImage repeatedly.
How can I save an image so I won't need to consistantly load it everytime I want to place it onto a canvas?

Comment: Just store a reference to the image inside a map or object literal.

Comment: @Keith Mind giving me an example of this in my case? Normally it'd be fine, but I'd need to wait for the load event to fire, and then store the reference. I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `loadImage` *memoized*, so you do not request new image if it is exactly same image, you can do this by making an in memory cache of the parameters you pass to the `loadImage` and return from it if they are same parameters.

Is your `tileData` ever changing? If not you do not even need to call the `loadImage` inside the `draw`.

Comment: Yeah, it changes every .5sec. I'll do that then, thank you :)

Comment: By the way if the arguments do not change but api still gives you different images this will be wrong. The question is if the api sends you the same image provided you send it same arguments in the request? But if not, so your api behaves like a pure function then you can safely do that memoization technique. Also if the argument change and th eresult does not change you can cache based on the images instead, to preserve memory. For that you need to somehow make  a comparison between images, I do not kow how, checking File properties may work for most cases but it is not silver bullet.